# Execute Python line of code in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm using Pydev with Eclipse. Is it possible to execute a line of python code or a text selection with my IDE? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possibile. What is the problem? What have you tried so far? Please, try to be more specific!

Comment: Sorry for that. My question was how to do it. I've just solve it following Nishant instructions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pydev documentation is available [here](http://pydev.org/manual.html)
For you specific issue I would suggest using the 'Interactive Console' built into PyDev the how-to is located [here](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html)

Also, if you're looking for additional short-cuts for PyDev you can look [here](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_keybindings.html)

Regards

Nishant

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL+ALT+ENTER` will execute the selected lines.