# Eclipse Pydev: Run selected lines of code

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Is there a command in Eclipse Pydev which allows me to only run a few selected (highlighted) lines of code within a larger script?

If not, is it possible to run multiple lines of code in the PyDev console at once?

Comment: Doesn't really answer your your question, but I use Python Tools with Visual Studio and you can send selections to interactive prompt using Ctrl-E,E.

Comment: Will console history multiple line execution help you?
See the link: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html

Comment: I searched for this after briefly using Jupyter Notebook.. can't believe how much productivity this will add!

Answer (score 19):

press `CTRL+ALT+ENTER` to send the selected lines to the interactive console

Comment: Is there a button to execute the line directly in the console?

Answer (score 14):

The solution is selecting and pressing **F2**, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664539/execute-python-line-of-code-in-eclipse) question or simply [this](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html#starting-the-interactive-console) section of the manual.

Comment: Both solutions work (Nic's and this one); but once you are in the interactive console (started using CTRL+ALT+DEL), then this one (i.e. pressing F2) is the intended solution.

Comment: It's exactly what i need. Thanks.